# MySQL COUNT does not return correct value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is my PHP code snippet:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbusername, $dbupassword, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`;";
$count = $conn->query($sql);
echo $count->num_rows;
```

It always echos 1 even though I have 5 users in my table (see image below). [image]

I also tried using `COUNT(1)` but it also returned 1. But when I change the statement to `` SELECT * FROM `users`; `` it returns 5.

If I do a `var_dump($count)` (same code as above but I don't use the num_rows), I get the information below:

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=> int(0)
  ["field_count"]=> int(1)
  ["lengths"]=> NULL
  ["num_rows"]=> int(1)
  ["type"]=> int(0)
}
```

I am running phpMyAdmin, Version information: 5.0.2, with database version: 10.4.14-MariaDB, and PHP 7.4.10

Comment: nope, it does return the correct value, it's `1` because when you execute the query `count()` you'll get one row. what you have to do is fetch the row, to get to the yielded value of `count()` which is `5`

Comment: I see.. I thought COUNT lets you count the total number of records in a table...

Comment: yes it does that, but the you need to fetch the record set to get to the value that `count()` showed you. just testing it in phpmyadmin should show 1 row. `COUNT(*)` then under that `5`. that's where you need fetch to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbusername, $dbupassword, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_row();
echo "row count = " . $row['0'];
var_dump($row);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to count the row of table, just run query "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`".
Its return one row that contain total table row. Dont use num_rows method, because "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`" query, just return one row